# After enabled repeater of router can't access WiFi

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I'm using *D-Link DIR 600M* as repeater on Linux Mint 18.2 KDE Plasma to access my mobile data with portable WiFi hotspot instead usb tether, but problem is **unable to access WiFi** right after release and renew IP so when I done, it lost.
Let me explain steps what I do:

1 Setup *WiFi router*  and ***enable repeater***   .
     ***And it's unable to connect because IP configuration conflict.***
 2 Editing network setting and set **IPV4** Method to Manual from Automatic and set  *Address, Gateway* and *Netmask* manually.
 3 Release & renew IP with `sudo dhclient -v -r enp3s0`
 4 Here I do unlike step 2. set up **IPV4** *Method* back to *Automatic*.
***That can connect but unable to access to router and connect WiFi***(With changed IP at configuring repeater).
**But repeater works.**

So where I mistake or is there any software or way to find IP can works to access WiFi router after enabling repeater?
Would appreciate help.
Thank you :-)

Comment: So you have the DIR 600M as a repeater for another wireless device? Can you give a better description of your network hardware?

Comment: @JohnnyVegas  Yes DIR 600M for my mobile data to share on it. 03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 03)

Comment: What revision DIR-600M is it? A1/B1/C1/D1

Comment: @JohnnyVegas It is C1 and F/W Ver.: 3.01

Comment: Change your other device to WPA encryption then reset DIR-600 and join the repeater again. Make sure you connect to the repeater SSID to test. Don't mess with network settings - Keep to DHCP only and use the linux GUI to change, Don't change via terminal.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas I tried but It's failed. Johnny there's two things one repeater set DHCP to none and when I manually set it DHCP Server mode on then I can connect to WiFi but internet doesn't work. Second thing is when I've to renew release IP from terminal internet work but WiFi doesn't. And doesn't matter with encryption. So I think there's need compromise either I've to choose WiFi or repeater. Thank you so much for paying your invaluable time :-)